# How to display a derivative

Tags: c#, .net, math, console, mathnet-numerics

Not sure this is the correct section of this site,but I have a question.

So,i`m using MathNet.Numerics to calculate a derivatives. I want to display them in console.

Code example

```
using System;
using MathNet.Numerics;

namespace math
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Func<double,double> f = x => 3 * Math.Pow(x, 3) + 2 * x - 6;
            var test = Differentiate.DerivativeFunc(f, 1);
            Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to display a complex number (real, imaginary)?  It is a two dimensional array   [ArrayReal(); ArrayImaginary()]

Comment: Not really,i want to display a function itselft. For example, if I derivate x^2 I want to display in console 2*x

Comment: It is a function : Ax^0 + Bx^1 + Cx^2 + Dx^3 + ... + Nx^N.  The Real and Imaginary arrays are [A,B,C,D, ..., N]

Comment: @DerzkeyBK Welcome on StackOverflow ;) I updated my answer because I think I found exactly what you were looking for. Please mark my answer as accepted / upvote it if it's what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question**

Let me reword your problem to make sure I understand and answer you correctly: Given the function `3x³ + 2x - 6` you would like to print in the console the equation of the derivative `9x² + 2`

**The library Math.NET Numerics can't do that**

This library does **calculation**. It does not try to construct the equation of the derivative.

Look: [Differentiate.DerivativeFunc](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/Differentiate.cs#L73) method returns a C# method `Func<double, double>` that takes a double as parameter, and returns a double as the result. This signature makes it impossible to retrieve the equation of **f'**. Go deeper in the code and see that the library is all about computing results with an approximation.

**However Math.NET Symbolics can**

https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/ is what you are looking for. I wrote the following code:

```
// using System;
// using MathNet.Symbolics;
// using Expr = MathNet.Symbolics.SymbolicExpression;

var x = Expr.Variable("x");
var func = 3 * (x * x * x) + 2 * x - 6;
Console.WriteLine("f(x) = " + func.ToString());

var derivative = func.Differentiate(x);
Console.WriteLine("f'(x) = " + derivative.ToString());
```

which prints in the console:

> f(x) = -6 + 2*x + 3*x^3
>
> f'(x) = 2 + 9*x^2

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what i needed.